# CONFIG_X86_64 flag and its usage

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64

I just checked my linux box's config file /boot/config_$(uname -r) and I found both of these flags are defined:

```
CONFIG_X86_64=y
CONFIG_X86=y
```

Shouldn't these 2 flags be exclusive to each other?

In addition, I am wondering whether these 2 flags should be used in kernel only because I saw many

```
 #ifdef CONFIG_X86_64
```

in kernel source code. Can user space application use this flag also?

In addition, since processor can be changed to compatibility mode from 64-bit mode.  If this change happens, for code that depend on CONFIG_X86_64 will all fail at run time, right?  How does application (kernel or user space) to detect whether machine is in 64 bit or compatibility mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`CONFIG_X86` is the flag targetting the *architecture*, the whole x86 family.
This includes both the 32-bit and 64-bit processors.

This can be seen by looking at the latest kernel (at the time of writing it is 4.15.1) [*Kconfig* file](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15.1/source/arch/x86/Kconfig)<sup>1</sup>

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0
# Select 32 or 64 bit
config 64BIT
    bool "64-bit kernel" if ARCH = "x86"
    default ARCH != "i386"
    ---help---
      Say yes to build a 64-bit kernel - formerly known as x86_64
      Say no to build a 32-bit kernel - formerly known as i386

config X86_32
    def_bool y
    depends on !64BIT

    #... other options removed

config X86_64
    def_bool y
    depends on 64BIT
```

In this file, config options are stripped of the `CONFIG_` prefix.
The `CONFIG_X86_64` is defined iif `CONFIG_64BIT` is defined, otherwise `CONFIG_X86_32` is.
Look at the `depends on` declaration to see it.

In a 64-bit kernel this command `cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep 'CONFIG_64BIT'` should return `CONFIG_64BIT=y`.

This is also confirmed in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41488) for a question on how to make a 32-bit config into a 64-bit one.

The antonym of `CONFIG_X86_64` is thus `CONFIG_X86_32`.

---

**TL;DR** `CONFIG_X86` is defined for all x86 processors, either bitness. `CONFIG_X86_64` is defined only for the *subset* of x86 processors supporting AMD64/IA32e.

---

<sup>1</sup> This link may change at any time soon. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362922/changing-domain-name-for-free-electrons?cb=1).